# event management php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, events, logging

i am working on a event kind website. What i am trying to do is, i show a form for broadasters to create their events for the particular date and then store them in the database. when the event date is current date then users will be coming to the site will click on that event link to watch the show. when they click on that link i don't want to show them the broadcasting page right away but instead i want to show them a small log in page, just to collect name and email so that at the back i can get their ip address to find the location. when i do this, how can i record no of users who are currently watching the same event, i am not sure if i should store each user with the event id and then count it for that event id and show on the broadcasting page. Is there any other approach? or if there is any clone script available?

regards

Answer (score 0):

Trying to distil the essence of your question here, from what I read you are looking for a way to show the Current Number of Users Online / Viewing a Specific Event?

If so, here are a couple of tutorials regarding Current Users Online counters, which might be adapted to your particular needs.

- [PHP User online tutorial](http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/9.html)
- [The Quickest Way to Count Online Users with PHP](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/PHP/The-Quickest-Way-To-Count-Users-Online-With-PHP/)

If I have misread your question, please edit it to make the specific question you are wanting answered clearer.

Comment: thanks, I think this will be helpful. Basically, I have some events list and when an user click on an event from homepage then I would like to record his ip at the back and then ask him to submit his name/email and after clicking submit he can view the cast. so if other users click on same event and then do the same process to watch it, i want to show total users watching this cast. I have some idea but still not sure how to work on this.

Comment: Quick suggestions/pointers: 1) You can record their IP against a `$_SESSION` on the initial pageload, 2) You can record the event they last visited and when they did, again, against a `$_SESSION` Identifier, 3) You can then calculate the (approx) number of current viewers (by using a MySQL query to show all visitors who last visited that event within the last X minutes).